# Exporting a shape made with modifier:boolean-difference

Tags: modifiers

I have made a new shape, using a boolean modifier. I subtract 1 shape from another, then hide the shape I subtracted & I'm left with the new shape. However. I am left with 2 objects, 1 being hidden, instead if 1 new shape. I want to export the new shape. ???

[image: Shape & Python code]

Comment: Click apply then export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **apply the modifier** first. Then you will have 1 shape. To do so you can either click *Apply* on the right in the *Properties Tab* or if you want to use python you can use `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier='newTray')`. But you need the object having the modifier selected for it to work. `tray.select = True` should do the trick. After that you'll still have to delete the object you subtracted from the other one (in your case *trayCutout*). To use python it's `bpy.ops.object.delete()`. Again, for it to work you need to select it first: `trayCutout.select = True` and deselect the other one `tray.select = False`.

So we have (if you want to delete trayCutout, otherwise you'll have to leave the last three lines out):

```
tray.select = True
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier='newTray')
trayCutout.select = True
tray.select = False
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I don't see any mention of Boolean nor Difference and I'm not able to follow your lead here. Can you flesh this instruction out a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in trying the export an stl file. With the 'Tray' selected, an 3ds file exports beautifully. Thanks to palkonimo.

[image: Final Code]

Comment: You should accept one of the answers so that everybody knows your issue is solved (click the check mark next to the answer)